# CSS ::part selector doesn't work for SVG in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, chromium

I am currently building a web application that use SVG to display cameras.
Within the SVG, the base camera draw is defined in a [`defs` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/defs), and real objects are then drawn using a [`use` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use).

Since those cameras can have different characteristics (e.g. online/active/selected/…), I'd like to style them. However, `use` tag creates a [closed shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot/mode), and therefore are inaccessible for standard CSS rule. I already use CSS variables successfully, but they present some limits.

I recently discovered the [`::part` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::part) which is **exactly** what I need: the object in `defs` exports some tags using a `part` attribute, and they are now accessible to CSS through `::part` selector. Nice!

Except that only Firefox seems to support it for SVG. Chrome does not. Here is a test: https://codepen.io/glandos/pen/LYOPerb The result should output a green camera with a red and black outlined path. In Chrom(e|ium), attributes from `defs` are used, but not the CSS.

Two questions:

1. I couldn't find any reported issue. Did I missed something? And since I don't have (and don't want) a Google account, I can't even report that to the Chromium team :'(
2. Is there a workaround, apart from going on with CSS variables that cascade through shadow DOM?

Comment: *Maybe* linked to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1269192 but honestly, it's hard to tell.

Comment: I would slim down your SVG to bare minimum, and report it at https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues (strictly not the correct place, but the best chance for a good response)

Comment: Done in https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/955 with the stripped down pen to https://codepen.io/glandos/pen/XWzWgbe.
Thanks for the advice.

Comment: This is still not resolved btw. Also facing the same issue. I had an aha moment when I tried this in Firefox first, then noticed it doesn't work in Chrome nor Safari.

Comment: The ticket in Chromium bugtracker (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1479000) was mentioned as blocked by another one (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=785246) which has been opened for nearly 5 years and it still has no ETA.